# How to make a queue of strings using user input?

Tags: c++, queue

I was wondering how to make a queue of strings requiring user input. Like for example, user will input a word then the word goes to queue. How does that work? I can only queue an integer for now. Sorry I'm a beginner and our professor doesn't teach us anything :(

Comment: It might be helpful to people who want to answer your question if you provide the code that your professor has shown for the integer queue

Comment: `std::queue<std::string>`

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the purpose of the questioner's task is to implement a queue by themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the default STD queue. Check out this documentation, [Queue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue)

The `std::queue` class is a container adapter that gives the programmer the functionality of a queue, specifically, a FIFO (first-in, first-out) data structure.

Note, this is very different from implementing a queue in **your own** designed `class` for such as a typical college course.

You just need to declare an `std::queue` of type `std::string`, example e.g. `std::queue<std::string> q`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <queue>
#include <stack>
#include <ostream>
#include <istream>

int main ()
{
  // Declare your queue of type std::string
  std::queue<std::string> q;

  // Push 1 to 3
  q.push ("1");
  q.push ("2");
  q.push ("3");

  // Declare a string variable
  std::string input;

  // Prompt
  std::cout << "- Please input a string: " << std::endl;

  // Catch user input and store
  std::cin >> input;

  // Push value inputted by the user
  q.push(input);

  // Loop while the queue is not empty, while popping each value
  while (not q.empty ())
    {
      // Output front of the queue
      std::cout << q.front () << std::endl;
      // Pop the queue, delete item
      q.pop ();
    }
  // New line, formatting purposes
  std::cout << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Exactly as @Raymond said, the `std::queue` is quite different from user-defined `queue`, because it uses templates in its definition (which means that you can have a `std::queue` of any type, while "college" definition is usually declared only for one type, for example `int`). If you want to know more about implementing your own queue, then you should definitely check [GeekForGeeks article about queues](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/queue-data-structure/). After reading that, you are going to understand queue data structure and will more likely understand new coming structures.

Comment: @whiskeyo Is correct, but for a user implemented queue, your struct/class for the queue implementation could also still use templated variables, just in case it is not usually in a single variable as he stated, such as `int`. I did not know if this would pertain to the OP's question. But wanted to say thanks for the great comment also.